# Complete Reference of Google Drive API PHP Client

Tags: google-api-php-client

Where can I find a complete reference of Google Drive API for PHP?

I have tried this (https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-php-client/main/) but it is empty.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for these links? http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/ or https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/latest/servicebuilder or https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: I would go with [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) or [docs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/tree/main/docs),  [samples](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Drive%20API)   Are you looking for something specific?

Comment: @Tanaike cloud lib doesn't work for google-apis as far as i know.

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for replying. Now, I could notice that I had misunderstood google-cloud-php and googleapis for PHP. Thank you.